# multidimensional index by array of indices in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, switch-statement, multidimensional-array

Is there a way in JavaScript to select a element of a multidimential array. Where the depth/rank/dimensionality is variable and the keys are given by a array of indices. Such that i don't have handle every possible dimentional depth separately. concretely speaking i want do get rid of switch cases like here:

```
/**
 * set tensor value by index
 * @type {array} indices [ index1, index2, index3 ] -> length == rank.
 * @type {string} value.
 */
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function( indices, value ) {
    var rank = indices.length;

    switch(rank) {
        case 0:
            this.values[0] = value;
        break;
        case 1:
            this.values[indices[0]] = value;
        break;
        case 2:
            this.values[indices[0]][indices[1]] = value;
        break;
        case 3:
            this.values[indices[0]][indices[1]][indices[2]] = value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Where **this.values** is a multidimensional array.

such that i get something that looks more like this:

```
/**
 * set tensor value by index
 * @type {array} indices, [ index1, index2, index3 ] -> length == rank
 * @type {string} value
 */
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function( indices, value ) {
    var rank = indices.length;

    this.values[ indices ] = value;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function( indices, value ) {
    var array = this.values;
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; ++i) {
        array = array[indices[i]];
    }
    array[indices[i]] = value;
}
```

This uses `array` to point to the nested array we are currently at and reads through the `indicies` for find the next `array` value from the current `array`.  Once we reach the last index in the `indices` list, we have found the array where we want to deposit the value. The final index is the slot in that final array where we deposit the value.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function( indices, value ) {
  var t = this, i;
  for (i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) t = t[indices[i]];
  t[indices[i]] = value;
}
```

Comment: No, he wants a *set* instead of a *get*

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function( indexes, value ) {
    var ref = this.values;  
    if (!indexes.length) indexes = [0];  
    for (var i = 0; i<indexes.length;i++) {
       if (typeof ref[i] === 'undefined') ref[i] = [];
       if (ref[i] instanceof Array) {  
           ref = ref[i];
       } else {
           throw Error('There is already value stored') 
       }
    } 
    ref = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? I'd say writing

```
tensor.values[1][5][8][2] = value;
```

is much more perspicuous than

```
tensor.setValues([1, 5, 8, 2], value);
```

If you really need to do that, it would be a simple loop over the array:

```
tensor.prototype.setValueByIndex = function(indices, value) {
    var arr = this.values;
    for (var i=0; i<indices.length-1 && arr; i++)
        arr = arr[indices[i]];
    if (arr)
        arr[indices[i]] = value;
    else
        throw new Error("Tensor.setValueByIndex: Some index pointed to a nonexisting array");
};
```

Comment: Yes it looks trivial but. I want to use a variable "number of indices" to create a abstract tensors such that the rank is equal to the "number of indices". such that all the operations can be defined in a abstract way instead of defining all the operations separately for the different ranks and dimensions

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It turns out to be pretty simple :P, Thanks!.