# Using a vector to index a multidimensional Fortran array

Tags: arrays, fortran

Is it possible in modern Fortran to use a vector to index a multidimensional array? That is, given, say,

```
integer, dimension(3) :: index = [4,6,9]
double precision, dimension(10,10,10) :: data
```

is there a better (more general) way to access `data(4,6,9)` than writing `data(index(1), index(2), index(3))`? It would be good not to have to hard-code the rank of the `data` array.

(Naively I would like to write `data(index)` but of course this actually means something different - subset "gathering" - requiring `data` to be a rank-one array itself.)

For what it's worth this is essentially the same question as [multidimensional index by array of indices in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019269/multidimensional-index-by-array-of-indices-in-javascript), but in Fortran instead. Unfortunately the clever answers there won't work with predefined array ranks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  And all the workarounds I can think of are ghastly hacks, you're better off writing a function to take `data` and `index` as arguments and spit out the element(s) you want.

You might, however, be able to use modern Fortran's capabilities for array rank remapping to do exactly the opposite, which might satisfy your wish to play fast-and-loose with array ranks.

Given the declaration

```
double precision, dimension(1000), target :: data
```

you can define a rank-3 pointer

```
double precision, pointer :: index_3d(:,:,:)
```

and then set it like this:

```
index_3d(1:10,1:10,1:10) => data
```

and hey presto, you can now use both rank-3 and rank-1 indices into `data`, which is close to what you want to do.  I've not used this in anger yet, but a couple of simple tests haven't revealed any serious problems.

Comment: @VladimirF: well, I can now do `data(sum([((index(i)-1)*10**(i-1), i=1, size(index))]) + 1)`... if I really want to!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: confirmation that there isn't a nice native way of doing this, and two sensible ways of getting around it... thanks!